# How can I finish this CURL request to OTRS 5.0?

Tags: curl, otrs

I'm trying to automatise a process in OTRS that is to look in specific queue to find all the closed ticket in the last 8 days. I want to do it in a bash script using Curl requests. So far i got this line working for me :

```
curl -sk "https://tstotrs.unil.ch/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/TimeToREST/TicketSearch?UserLogin=$user&Password=$pass&Queue=62&StateIDs=$stateid" -X GET |jq -r .TicketID[]
```

It gives me a list of TicketID that are closed in the queue number 62. The problem I encounter is that i want to transform them into ticket number not only ticket ID and I wish to add a condition that says only the one closed the last 8 days.

I'm stuck trying to do the loop to transform ticketID in ticket numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, they added an API for it where you can use minutes as value.

> TicketCloseTimeNewerMinutes => 120

for the two last hours for example.
Best wishes.